# Error parsing JSON with Android I get a null instead of correct data

Tags: java, android, json, google-books

This app is supposed to parse some JSON data (hard coded for now) from the Google Books API, and pass an ArrayList of Books to the adapter that will display it on a ListView. The problem I have is that the JSON parse is returning null instead of the parsed data. I Don't know where the problem is exactly but I suspect it has to be either in the HTTPManager class or the BookJSONParser class. I will include all the code just in case. I appreciate any help Thanks!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

ProgressBar pBar;
List<MyTask> tasks;

ArrayList<Book> bookList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    pBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    Button sButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.s_button);
    sButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    tasks = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.s_button: {
            if (isOnline()) {
                new MyTask().execute("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=millionare"); //https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=soft+skills

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

protected boolean isOnline() {

    ConnectivityManager connectManager = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo netInfo = connectManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

protected void updateDisplay(ArrayList<Book> showBooklist) {
    bookList = showBooklist;

    if (bookList != null) {
        BookAdapter adapter = new BookAdapter(this, bookList);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No content", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return HttpManager.getData(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        bookList = BookJSONParser.parseFeed(result);
        updateDisplay(bookList);
    }

}

}
```

---

```
public class HttpManager {

public static String getData(String myUrl) throws IOException {

    InputStream inputStream = null;

    int len = 10000;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(myUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        connection.connect();

        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

        // Convert the InputStream into a string
        String contentAsString = readIt(inputStream, len);
        return contentAsString;

        // Makes sure that the InputStream inputStream closed after the app inputStream
        // finished using it.
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

        }
    }
}

// Reads an InputStream and converts it to a String.
public static String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Reader reader = null;
    reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
    char[] buffer = new char[len];
    reader.read(buffer);
    return new String(buffer);
}
}
```

---

```
public class BookJSONParser {

public static ArrayList<Book> parseFeed(String content) {

    ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(content);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String name = object.getString("title").toString();

            Book book = new Book(name);
            bookList.add(book);

        }
        return bookList;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
}
```

---

```
public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book> {

public BookAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Book> bookList) {
    super(context, 0, bookList);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertedView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View listItemView = convertedView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    Book currentBook = getItem(position);

    TextView locationName = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_title);

    locationName.setText(currentBook.getTittle());

    return listItemView;

}
}
```

---

```
public class Book {

private String mTittle;

/**
 * This is the constructor.
 * @param title is the book title being passed in.
 */
public Book(String title) {
    mTittle = title;

}

public String getTittle() {
    return mTittle;
}

public void setTittle(String tittle) {
    mTittle = tittle;
}

}
```

Comment: Instead of asking the same question 2 times you better modify your old question [Android: JSON parse: null object reference when attempting to parse JSON into a ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134696/android-json-parse-null-object-reference-when-attempting-to-parse-json-into-a)..!!